# Why a hyperplane is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Given a nonzero vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a scalar $b \in \mathbb{R}$, we define the hyperplane
$$
H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; | \; a^T x = b\}.
$$

Let $x$ and $y$ be any two vectors that belong to $H$, clearly $a^T (x - y) \neq b$ (unless $b = 0$), that is, $x - y$ is not in $H$.

Furthermore, the zero vector is not in $H$ unless $b = 0$.

**So why a general hyperplane is a subspace?**

Comment: It is not (by your reason).

Comment: "*So why a general hyperplane is a subspace?*"  Take a look at what was said and be sure you read it correctly.  I suspect you read it wrong.  What is true is that a general subspace (*of $\Bbb R^n$*) *is a hyperplane* but not vice versa (*lines simply being one-dimensional hyperplanes, etc...*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly note, hyperplanes are not necessarily "vector subspaces", which can be seen from the fact that they do not contain the zero vector.

However, every hyperplane is an [affine subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces_and_parallelism) of $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. It is not a subspace, but an [affine subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces_and_parallelism).